# Being a good citizen displaying MKRouteSteps

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

In lack of a better title...

I'm am writing a custom turn-by-turn implementation in an app used for tracking as well as giving directions using `CLLocation` and `MKMapView`.

Getting a route for a given address, displaying it with the returned polyline, getting an ETA and a distance and displaying those all seems fairly trivial and easily implemented. One thing that there isn't a lot of guidance on though, is how to display `MKRouteStep`'s returned in the `MKRoute` object. All guides online either don't bother mentioning them, or skip over them fairly easily by simply displaying them at once in a table view. Obviously not the most gracious solution, and in my opinion a critical part that's missing.

One solution I did find (can't find the SO answer I saw it in) mentioned creating a CLRegion for each step. So I wen't ahead and created my own implementation of it:

```
private func drawRouteOnMap() {
        viewModel.getRouteForDelivery() { route in
            if let route = route {
                self.polyline = route.polyline
                self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: .AboveRoads)

                //Add the route steps to the currentRouteSteps array for later retrieval
                self.currentRouteSteps = route.steps
                //Set the routeStepLabels text property to the first step of the route.
                if let step = route.steps.first {
                    self.routeStepLabel.text = step.instructions
                }
                //Iterate over the steps in the `MKRoute` object. Create each region to monitor with the identifier set to an Int
                var i = 0
                for step in route.steps {
                    let coord = step.polyline.coordinate
                    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: coord, radius: 20.0, identifier: "\(i)")
                    self.locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
                    i += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I can listen to the `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {}` delegate method

```
private func updateUIForRegion(oldRegion:CLRegion) {

    if let regionID = Int(oldRegion.identifier),
    steps = currentRouteSteps {
        //Fetch the step for the next region
        let step = steps[regionID + 1]
        routeStepLabel.text = step.instructions
    }
}
```

Then when we exit the view controller

```
@IBAction func shouldDismissDidPress(sender: AnyObject) {
        for (_, region) in locationManager.monitoredRegions.enumerate() {
            locationManager.stopMonitoringForRegion(region)
        }
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This all works fairly well actually. But where things start to fall apart is if a user presses the home button when in the turn by turn navigation VC or if the app crashes. The app will not stop monitoring the regions set up until the locationManager is told to stop monitoring for them, even if the app is force closed. I wouldn't want the app to terminate all the region monitoring anyways, as the navigation wouldn't work when the user resumes the app. It just feels like the region monitoring isn't really the *correct* way to display the `MKRouteStep`'s, but I'm out of ideas how to do it in another way.

Any ideas / better implementations are welcomed

Answer (score 0):

So, first, the way that works is by definition the most elegant way - so if you have some code that handles every possibility, then by all means go for it!

With that in mind, for cases where there isn't a frank crash but your app is closed could you use one of the many delegate calls in `AppDelegate` to cease your monitoring?

Comment: Sorry, see the updated question. Basically, If I stop monitoring for the regions, then once the user resumes the app, the turn by turn would no longer work, unless I recalculate the entire route. Which ofcourse is another posibility